# Issue with Default Binding behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Reading this [FreeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-this-in-javascript) about the `this` keyword in JS. I ran some of the sample code but I'm getting a totally different output.

```js
function alerty() { 
  console.log(this.named + ' is calling'); 
}

const named = 'Kingsley'; 
alerty(); // Kingsley is calling'
```

- `alerty()` logs `"undefined is calling`" instead of `"Kingsley is calling"` specified in the article.
- I did not specify `'use strict';` anywhere.
- Why could this be happening?

Comment: BTW, `alert()` is already a function in the DOM - you should use unused names for your own functions, variables and types.

Comment: Where and how are you running this code, btw? When I run it I get `" is calling"` as output (because `window.name` is `""` by default).

Comment: No matter how the code is run, `const name = ...` cannot result in a property `name` being created on `this`.

Comment: Using *var named = 'Kingsley'* in a browser, makes it log *Kingsley is calling*. It always logs *undefined is calling* in a node environment, whether I use *var* or *const*. Would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @Abaga NodeJS doesn't have an implicit `global` object for `this` to be bound to - but in browsers the `window` object is `global` and is bound to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Kling already mentioned in the comments:

Declaring a local variable using `const` will not make it a global object property.

So `const name = 'Kingsley';` sets a local variable, while `name = 'Kingsley';` will set a global object (`window`) property and is therefore equal to `window.name = 'Kingsley';`.

Since `this` is assigned to `window` on the global level, `name = 'Kingsley';` will effectively set `this.name` *in this very particular example*.

Note that I am assuming that you are not using JavaScript modules.